# How to get left padding on UITextField leftView image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am setting up a `UIImageView` as a `leftView` on a `UITextField` like so:

```
UIImageView *envelopeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.height*.1, self.height*.1)];
envelopeView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"envelope.png"];
envelopeView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
envelopeView.bounds = CGRectInset(envelopeView.frame, 15, 10);
self.emailAddress.leftView = envelopeView;
self.emailAddress.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

which gets me the following:

[image: UITextField image]

As you can see the left size of the image goes right up to the left edge of the button even though I tried to set an inset. How can I move this envelope in so that it's got padding on all sides?

---

Update: I tried the proposed answer of changing the `UIImageView` frame like so, but the envelope is still lined up on the left side at the border of the `UITextField`:

```
CGFloat padding = 20;
UIImageView *envelopeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3*padding, padding, self.height*.1-padding, self.height*.1-padding)];
```

Comment: did you try to change CGRectMake(5, 0, self.height*.1, self.height*.1)] for example ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]you can simply try this:

```
    UIImageView *envelopeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 30, 30)];
    envelopeView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comment-128.png"];
    envelopeView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
  UIView *test=  [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 30, 30)];
    [test addSubview:envelopeView];
    [self.textField.leftView setFrame:envelopeView.frame];
    self.textField.leftView =test;
        self.textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: just tried this, but it shows no effect. The image is the approximately the same.

Comment: how much did you give for x ?

Comment: x can not be CGFloat .. it is like on the x-Axis, should be some integer.

Comment: @SimonaMi are you sure? I use a float for x all the time.

Comment: i always used it with int, but you are right, this is from the apple documentation CGRect CGRectMake ( CGFloat x, CGFloat y, CGFloat width, CGFloat height );
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectMake

Comment: i tried with a diff image , pls change the image name

Comment: Also dont worry about the other items you see in the screenshot. Just look at the text field

Comment: @Mr.T yes so the solution is to put the UIImageView inside a UIView? any idea why this works?

Comment: it will also work for uuiimageview too. Try to set the frame for leftview

Comment: uiimageview is also a fmaily of uiview. it doesnt matter if you put imageview in a view or put  imageview directly. YOu need to set the frame of the textfield.leftview

Answer (score 26):

**For Swift 3 Users**

Here is what worked for me:

```
extension UITextField {

 /// set icon of 20x20 with left padding of 8px 
 func setLeftIcon(_ icon: UIImage) {

    let padding = 8
    let size = 20

    let outerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size+padding, height: size) )
    let iconView  = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: padding, y: 0, width: size, height: size))
    iconView.image = icon
    outerView.addSubview(iconView)

    leftView = outerView
    leftViewMode = .always  
  }
}
```

test:

```
txOrigin.setLeftIcon(icon_location)
```

result:

[image]

Comment: superb solution

Comment: Still works perfectly on Swift 5!
Thanks bro for saving my day!

Answer (score 9):

**For Swift 4.2 +**

You can use this extension:

```
extension UITextField {
    func leftImage(_ image: UIImage?, imageWidth: CGFloat, padding: CGFloat) {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: padding, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: frame.height)
        imageView.contentMode = .center
        
        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth + 2 * padding, height: frame.height))
        containerView.addSubview(imageView)
        leftView = containerView
        leftViewMode = .always
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a champ!  Thanks.  Very easy to duplicate for the rightView also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. Change your frame according to your need.

```
NSTextAttachment*   placeholderImageTextAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
placeholderImageTextAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Search"];
placeholderImageTextAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -2, 16, 16);
NSMutableAttributedString*  placeholderImageString = [[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:placeholderImageTextAttachment] mutableCopy];
 NSMutableAttributedString*  placeholderString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:NSLocalizedString(@"   Search", nil)];
[placeholderImageString appendAttributedString:placeholderString];
 _txtFieldSearch.attributedPlaceholder = placeholderImageString;
_txtFieldSearch.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```