# CGRect X no effect in the TextField

Tags: ios, swift

If you see my code I am trying to add 13 px padding from left of the `city label` in the textfield but it is not working. I am not sure what is going on there.

Here Is my textField

```
var cityTextField : RightPaddingTextField = {

       var textField = RightPaddingTextField() 
        textField.textAlignment = .right
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        var label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 13, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
        label.text = "City"
        textField.leftViewMode = .always
        textField.leftView = label
        return textField

    }()
```

Here setup constraints:

```
 func cityLabelWithTextFieldSetup(){

        addSubview(cityTextField)


        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : cityTextField]))

        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0" : cityTextField]))

    }
```

I am trying to achieve it like in this image but it's not working.

[image]

**UPDATE**

here is my code output please check only `city` row ..

[image]

Comment: Do you get any constraint issue?

Comment: "It's not working." What does that mean?

Comment: This is the normal behaviour. Because when you initialized your label, you are adding constraints. Your constraints says that the width and height properties will be same with the superview.

Comment: You can try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42849074/934710

Comment: @Fogmeister update my question could check that please

Comment: @Fogmeister please help me  .. or give some hints how can i achieved please

Comment: @pckill it is not working for me .. cause i doing .. textfield ..

Comment: @ridvankucuk no constraint issue